# Average stats in ns2 simulation

Tags: graph, tcl, ns2

Hi guys i need your help. I am making a simulation to compare some protocols regarding average stats and i have to make the graphs. I use this code and make my modifications.
http://www.nipunharitash.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/xgraph.txt
I have 2 questions:
a)  How can i calculate the average throughput,packet loss and packet delay in this example? I need only one graph in each case that shows the average.
b)Is there any way to calculate the jitter too?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xgraph.txt is actually the classic wireless-udp-1.tcl (+ other namings). Probably not the best choice for Jitter analyzes, as the main trace file = `trace2.tr` contains no Jitter information.

Analyzing throughput https://github.com/WiNG-NITK/APP-Tool

```
--Average throughput--


       startTime:  0

        stopTime:  79

    receivedPkts:  61508

   avgTput[kbps]:  111568


---------------------
```

And Instant throughput ... [image]

The text output, Instant throughput : w-udp__Inst.Thr.txt ... and all **~150  Xgraph simulation** examples → 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZUxlTHhkOTdqNVU?usp=sharing

Analyzing scripts, "top 20" https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNUnRKbmhMdFNyQU0/view?usp=sharing

All awk etc. scripts https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNOW9HaHVoaHZzRWs/view?usp=sharing

All ~2500 simulation examples https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

---

P.S. : Simple examples, jitter → `1-DSDV-adhoc.tcl  2-AODV-adhoc.tcl  3-DSR-adhoc.tcl  AODV-nn10.tcl  DSDV-nn10.tcl  DSR-nn10.tcl` → https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNY0E2aVJ4UTlVSXc?usp=sharing → See Jit_results.